# Do I need to have a water supply connected to a refrigerator to seal the plumbing against microbes?

Tags: water, refrigerator

I bought a new fridge and moved the old one to the basement. **Do I need to connect water supply to the old fridge to stop contamination of the lines, and water filter, by bacteria?** I don't need the ice or water down there, but I don't want to damage the units either.

Answer (score 2):

If you don’t use the lines over time things will grow in poly tubing, but copper not as much. If you have a plug for the line it will keep it from dribbling and collecting contaminants, but the lines will need to be flushed after a period of no use.

Answer (score 0):

Once the supply lines for the fridge have had all the water evaporated there won't an environment for mold to grow. The same can be said for bacteria.

You may be able to facilitate the evaporation by opening the hose somewhere in the water supply line which would allow the water to drain faster. If there is a disposable filter it should be removed as it will  be difficult to remove all water from it's filter medium.

Once the water is removed a plug inserted at the open hose end or crimping it with tape will seal the water system.

If and/or when it is attached to a water source flushing the line is a wise idea. And a new filter will keep contaminants out.